# ActiveRecord pattern & race conditions

Tags: activerecord, concurrency, race-condition

I've been scratching my head for a bit on an elegant solution to tackle this problem (which doesn't seem to have been addressed that much).

I love the fluidity of the [Active Record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern), but it seems to be very susceptible to race conditions as you might have a hundred independent "authoritative" copies of state at the same time (with a busy enough web application).

For example, what if I have a page which gives players points with code like this:

```
$user = User::fromUsername($username);
$user->points++;
$user->save();
```

... and another page which subtracts points, like this:

```
$user = User::fromUsername($username);
$user->points -= 100;
$user->save();
```

What happens if both of these pages are called at almost the same time? I imagine if they execute in the proper order (completely sequentially) everything will work out fine, however, what if the second page reads state from the database before the first has run but saves afterwards?

Is it even possible to address this problem within ActiveRecord? What are best practices for mitigating this (locks everywhere?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that operations should be atomic

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_operation

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking about - what the best way is to make sure actions on ActiveRecord objects are atomic...

Comment: well, I'm not sure that a downvote is the right way of thanking me for providing the vocabulary for your problem. Anyway, you say that the problem hasn't been adressed, but frameworks like redis manage a transaction queue to make them atomic. http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html

Comment: I apologize for the downvote - not sure what I was thinking there. Unfortunately, can't revert it now. I think that I should clarify the wording of the question, and thanks for pointing that out. I'll try to do so tomorrow.